# Group same elements of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

Suppose I have an array a=['a','b','c','a','b','c']. I want to get the result **a a b b c c**. I have tried this code but I am getting **a
b
b
c
a
b
b
c**.I am not allowed to use **sorted(aa)**.  I am looking for help to my code rather than an alternative.

```
aa=['a','b','c','a','b','c','a']
i=0
while len(aa) > i:
    x=i
    j=1
    p=len(aa)-1
    while j <p:
        if (aa[x]==aa[j]):
        print (aa[x])
    j=j+1
i=i+1
```

Comment: `>>> sorted(aa)`

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter? Are you looking for help fixing your code, or just a working solution? What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: @Rawing looking for help fixing my code. See edit.

Comment: You have a lot of indentation errors

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're overthinking things. Simply sorting `aa` should give the result you wanted:

```
>>> aa=['a','b','c','a','b','c']
>>> sorted(aa)
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Yes but i am not supposed to use sorted(aa) here.

Comment: @AshutoshChapagain You should include all requirements in the question. We can't read your mind...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it divided by spaces, try this:

```
aa=['a','b','c','a','b','c']
aa.sort()
print(' '.join(aa))
```

And if the order doesn't matter you could try this:

```
aa=['a','b','c','a','b','c']
''.join([aa.count(elem)*elem for elem in set(aa)])
```